# How to Convert SQL TimeStamp in this format "1394039043000" to String

Tags: android, timestamp, simpledateformat

I am using the method below but there is an hour difference in the converted timestamp

```
public static String getServerFormattedDate(String dateStr) {


    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(Long.valueOf(dateStr)); // input date in
                                                                    // Timestamp
                                                                    // format

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(ts);
            cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, +7); // Time different between UTC and PDT is +7
                                        // hours
            String convertedCal = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()); // This String
                                                                    // is converted
                                                                    // datetime
            /* Now convert String formatted DateTime to Timestamp */

            return convertedCal;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do timezone math on the timestamp yourself. Instead, keep it in UTC and set the timezone on the `DateFormat`. For example:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PDT"));
Date date = new Date(Long.valueOf(dateStr));
String convertedCal = dateFormat.format(date);
```

By default `SimpleDateFormat` uses timezone settings appropriate for the current default locale and that can explain the 1 hour difference you're seeing.